# DataBase issue in nokia devices S40 J2ME

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-me

I am developing app for nokia s40 series, I am using [Floggy database](http://floggy.sourceforge.net/).

On simulator read and write operations perform perfectly fine and displaying data in list as my need.

But on device the data is not displayed from database.

device c3 and X3-02
simulator nokia sdk

Comment: Sometimes the floggy is not supported by your device.Please check your device vendor's site.